# AngularJS Filter for ng-repeat don't work after data changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm have data in object (not array).

and in HTML i'm have

```
ng-repeat="type in types | toArray | orderBy:'order'"
```

This need for - orderBy works only if data is array, but in $scope i'm need data in object.
So it's works onload.

But if data changed, for example added new type - order don't works.

Somehow can I reinitialize ng-repeat or do something that it would work?

Code of filter toArray:

```
angular.module(........).filter("toArray", function(){
    return function(obj) {
        var result = [];
        angular.forEach(obj, function(val, key) {
            val.$$hashKey = key;
            result.push(val);
        });
        return result;
    };
});
```

Comment: oh - it's strang - it's works fine - but if order != 1 - if order == 1 it's last

Comment: Provide a plunker, and explain why are you creating `$$hashKey`?

Comment: for save keys of object in array